# How do i check if i tem already exist in ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `ToolStripMenuItem` `MouseEnter` event:

```
private void recentFilesToolStripMenuItem_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem s = new ToolStripMenuItem(lines[i]);
            if (!recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.ContainsKey(lines[i]))
            recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(s);

    }            
}
```

Now I am using `ContainsKey` but before i tried only with Contains(s)
In both cases it keep adding the items over and over again to the DropDownItems.
Each time i move the mouse and Enter i see the items added again.
In this case lines is array of string contain paths and names of text files.

For example in lines index 0 i see: `d:\mytext.txt`

The problem is that it keep adding them over again when i enter with the mouse and i want them to be added only once.

First time i see when entering with the mouse:

```
d:\mytext.txt
e:\test.txt
c:\hello\hellowowrld.txt
```

Next time when I enter with the mouse I see it twice:

```
d:\mytext.txt
e:\test.txt
c:\hello\hellowowrld.txt
d:\mytext.txt
e:\test.txt
c:\hello\hellowowrld.txt
```

Then next time i see the same items 9 times and so on.

Comment: Contains checks for object equality. You're adding a `ToolStripMenuItem`, but checking if some other object (`String` maybe?) exists there. So they will never match. You need to provide your own way of checking, probably looping and checking the text inside the `ToolStripMenuItem`

Comment: You need either to clear your `DropDownItems` before re-adding them, else put a check that they don't already exist before re-adding them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

One, is that you create your `ToolStripMenuItem` like this:

```
new ToolStripMenuItem(lines[i], (Image)null, (EventHandler)null, lines[i]);
```

It's that fourth parameter that is the "key" for `.ContainsKey(...)`, not the first parameter.

Two, you can do it this way:

```
if (!recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems
        .Cast<ToolStripMenuItem>()
        .Any(x => x.Text == lines[i]))
{
    recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(s);
}
```

This second way searches the actual text.